# LESS CSS Extend function not working as expected

Tags: css, less

I have a style set up using extend. The problem is, under certain circumstances, it isn't working and it doesn't seem logical.

I've simplified the CSS but the problem is still the same. Here's some nested classes:

```
#how-it-works {
    .timeline {
        & > .timeline-step {

            & > h3:extend(.h3-text) {}
        }
    }
}
```

In the above instance LESS doesn't output the CSS.

However, if I remove the outer layer like this:

```
.timeline {
    & > .timeline-step {

        & > h3:extend(.h3-text) {}
    }
}
```

I get the output I need:

```
.h3-text,
h3:not([class]),
.timeline > .timeline-step > h3,
.legal-info dt,
.call-to-action .rapr {
  color: #424242;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 28px;
}
```

It doesn't matter whether the outer style is a class or an ID.

Anyone throw any light on the situation?

Comment: Very weird, need to look into the docs because this - `#how-it-works { & .timeline {` works (note the `&` at the start). It is only a workaround for now and if you want me to post it as answer I will do so. I think answer area is the correct place because comments can go unnoticed but I'm not sure if you already knew that option and want to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Harry - your answer does indeed work. I wasn't aware of the answer so I thinks it's best you create an answer. I've come across this behaviour before but it wasn't so clear cut-it's very likely that others have too-so workaround or not, it's a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very weird kind of behavior and currently I don't have an explanation as to why it works this way but there is a workaround. It seems to work if we use the parent selector (`&`) at all levels before the actual nested selector (except the inner-most one).

Considering for how long the `:extend()` feature has existed and how common this scenario seems to be, it could possibly be an intended feature. I will add more explanation about the reason once I've managed to find it :)

```
.h3-text{
    color: #424242;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 28px;
}    
#how-it-works {
    & .timeline {
        & > .timeline-step {
           & > h3:extend(.h3-text) {};
        }
    }
}
```

---

Another approach that also seems to work is to avoid the `&` (parent selector) at all levels. It shouldn't be a big problem for this particular scenario because the `&` is basically doing nothing.

```
.h3-text{
    color: #424242;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 28px;
}    
#how-it-works {
    .timeline {
        > .timeline-step {
             > h3:extend(.h3-text) {};
        }
    }
}
```

---

Even `:extend` inside a ruleset works. Seems like the problem happens when `:extend` attached to a selector is used and the selector has `&` only at some levels.

```
.h3-text{
    color: #424242;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 28px;
} 
#how-it-works {
    .timeline {
        & > .timeline-step {
             & > h3 {
                &:extend(.h3-text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Second option is better because you're not adding anything extra - just use & in these situations for readability.

Comment: @JohnOhara: I've added another option also. Seems like there are multiple ways to workaround this problem but I am not any closer to finding the reason :(

Comment: Very odd. With the number of workarounds, it could be an bug - unfortunately for me, I'm an absolute star at finding things that don't work.